$\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz$

Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz;\quad \gamma(r)(t)=re^{it};\quad t \in [0, \pi];\quad r>0$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz & =
\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z-1+1}{z}dz=\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z-1}{z}dz+\lim_{ r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{1}{z}dz
\\[2mm] & =\lim_{ r \to 0}\left[F(-r)-F(r)+\pi {\rm i}\right] = \pi{\rm i}
\end{align}
where $F$ is a primitive of the analytic function $\left({\rm e}^{z} - 1\right)/z$ that exists as its domain is a simply connected region. Is this alright ?. Any other alternatives ?.

You don't need to use the fact that $g(z)=\frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}$ has a primitive, it suffices to know that $g(z)$ is continuous at $z=0$ (that is, if we set $g(0)=\lim_{z\to 0} g(z) =1$). Indeed if $g$ is continuous at $z=0$ then there is an $r_0$ such that $|g(z)|<|g(0)|+1$ for all $z\in B(0,r_0)$. Thus for $r<r_0/2$ we have
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma(r)} g(z)dz\right|
= \left|\int_0^\pi g(re^{it})ire^{it}dt\right|\leq \int_0^\pi r|g(\gamma(t))|dt \leq \pi\cdot r\cdot (|g(0)|+1)|\to 0
$$
as $r \to 0$, hence
$$
\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{\gamma(r)}\frac{e^z}{z} dz = \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)}\left(g(z)+\frac{1}{z}\right)dz = \pi\cdot i.
$$
The same technique will work to evaluate $\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \int_{\gamma_{z_0,r}} f(z)dz$, whenever

the family of arcs $\gamma_{z_0,r}$ are given by $\gamma_r(t)=z_0+r\exp(it)$, $t \in (\theta_0,\theta_1)$ and thus trace out the arc of a circle centred at $z_0$ with radius $r$ with a fixed range of argument $\theta_0\leq t \leq \theta_1$, and

$f$ has a simple pole of at $z_0$.



It is correct ($\frac{e^z - 1}{z}$ is an entire function). Other possible solution:
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz = \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{e^{re^{it}}}{re^{it}}ire^{it} dt = \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} ie^{re^{it}} dt = \int_{0}^{\pi} \lim_{r\to 0} ie^{re^{it}} dt = \int_{0}^{\pi} i dt = \pi i$$

Use Taylor series(maybe too big tool to this problem):
$$\int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz=
\int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{1}{z}dz
+\int_{\gamma(r)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}dz
=\pi i+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\gamma(r)}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}dz\\
=\pi i+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n\cdot n!}\bigg|_{r}^{-r}
=\pi i+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-r)^n+r^n}{n\cdot n!}.$$
So
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{\gamma(r)} \frac{e^z}{z}dz
=\pi i+\lim_{r \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-r)^n+r^n}{n\cdot n!}
=\pi i+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{(-r)^n+r^n}{n\cdot n!}
=\pi i.$$
